# LIBSVM "Warning: using -h 0 may be faster"

Tags: time-series, svm, forecasting, matlab, libsvm

I am using `LIBSVM` package (Matlab version) in order to perform wind power forecasting. My training dataset is quite big, approx. 52000 values of 4 parameters.

The code seems to run correctly but is quite slow and I get the following message:

```
WARNING: using -h 0 may be faster
```

**What does that mean and what do I have to change in my code?**

Comment: Add the `-h 0` flag to your options string. Basically it means that no shrinking heuristics will be used by the solver.

Answer (score 10):

This means, that optimization algorithm detected that with high probability (not in the strict, mathematical sense) you can speed up your training by turning the `-h 0` flag in your options. Basically, `-h` is the shrinking heuristics, implemented in the libsvm package which for some data significantly reduces number of required computations, while in others - makes it slower. There is no general rule, but there are some heuristics regarding this heuristic, which "detect" when it could help - and this is exactly the reason for this message - one of such "metaheuristics" detected, that for your particular data and parameters - it could be more valuable to set the `-h 0` flag.

If you are interested in more details regarding this possible optimization speed up you could refer to the source paper:

*T. Joachims, [Transductive Inference for Text Classification using Support Vector Machines](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~dplewis/candidacy/joachims99transductive.pdf). International Conference on Machine Learning (ICML), 1999.*

Comment: For folks (like me) reading this and using `sklearn`, use `shrinking=False`.